# BACnet broadcasts with 2 subnets on one VLAN

Tags: vlan, broadcast

I have a building automation network configuration with mechanical equipment on subnet 10.233.138.0/24 and electrical equipment on subnet 10.233.136.0/23.  BACnet uses broadcasts for certain functions (discovery) which are typically blocked by an IP router, therefore BBMDs (bacnet broadcast mgt devices) are set up on each subnet to handle the broadcasts by sending a unicast between the BBMDs.  If both of these subnets are configured to be on the same VLAN, will broadcast reach the other subnet without the need of BBMDs?

Comment: Applications using broadcast are becoming obsolete because companies are refusing to use such applications, and IPv6 does not even have broadcast so such applications cannot be ported to IPv6. For a few decades now, we use multicast instead of broadcast, and multicast can be routed.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The BBMDs need to be on each subnet that you have devices on.